# Understanding Haskell Map.lookup (Example in LYH)

Tags: haskell

I'd appreciate help understanding the origin of the extra `map` in `Map.lookup lockerNumber map`, from the following example taken from chapter 8 of [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-synonyms)

```
lockerLookup :: Int -> LockerMap -> Either String Code  
lockerLookup lockerNumber map =   
    case Map.lookup lockerNumber map of   
        Nothing -> Left $ "Locker number " ++ show lockerNumber ++ " doesn't exist!"  
        Just (state, code) -> if state /= Taken   
                                then Right code  
                                else Left $ "Locker " ++ show lockerNumber ++ " is already taken!"
```

Comment: Map is a confusing variable name here. It is not the map function.

Comment: So `map` is the value?

Comment: Yes, a `LockerMap` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly put, here `map` is a variable of type `LockerMap`, which I assume to be of the form `Data.Map.Map someKeyType someValueType`. It represents a (finite) association between elements of `someKeyType` and those of `someValueType`. This is sometimes also called a (finite) mapping, (finite) function, dictionary, hash, etc.

The expression `Map.lookup x map` simply accesses the `map` with key value `x`. The result is `Nothing` is there is no association for `x` in the `map`, and `Just v` if `x` is associated with value `v`.

Comment: So `lockerNumber` in `case Map.lookup lockerNumber map` is a type! I thought "Type synonyms (and types generally) can only be used in the type portion of Haskell" (I'm quoting the book here).

Comment: @Olumide No, `lockerNumber` is a value of the type "keys in the map", which above I called `someKeyType`.

Comment: Oops . I was confusing `LockerMap` for `lockerMap`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "additional" `map` (as in `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`) in that code. It gets more clear if we rename `map` to `m`:

```
lockerLookup :: Int -> LockerMap -> Either String Code  
lockerLookup lockerNumber m =   
    case Map.lookup lockerNumber m of   
      -- snip
```

Now you just need to remember that `Map.lookup` has type `Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Maybe a` and therefore you need to supply a `Map`. Luckily, the second argument (`m`) is a `LockerMap`, which is the same as `Map Int (LockerState, Code)`.